# Two different results for the same integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Calculating the principal value of the integral in version 13 on Windows 10,
I obtain

```
a = Integrate[Exp[I*s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2) - Exp[I*s], {s, -Infinity, Infinity},
PrincipalValue -> True]
```

> `2 I \[Pi] ((E^(I Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 1, 0]) Root[ 1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 1, 0])/ (1 - 4 Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 1, 0] +  4 Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 1, 0]^3) +  ( E^(I Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 2, 0]) Root[ 1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 2, 0])/ ( 1 - 4 Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 2, 0] +  4 Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 2, 0]^3) + ( E^(I Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 4, 0]) Root[ 1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 4, 0])/( 1 - 4 Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 4, 0] +  4 Root[1 + # - 2 #^2 + #^4& , 4, 0]^3)`

```
 N[a]
```

> `-1.414 + 0.192275 I`

That integral can be treated as the value of the Fourier transform at the unit up to a multiplier `Sqrt[2*Pi]`:

```
b=FourierTransform[1/(1 + x/(x^2 - 1)^2) - 1, x, s] // ToRadicals;
N[Sqrt[2*Pi]*b /. s -> 1]
```

> `-0.998307 - 0.313707 I`

I am sure both calculations apply [that formula](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0dnl7wpxba0fu8/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-03-21%2020.34.34.png?dl=0).
Three terms in `a` confirm it in view of

```
sol = Solve[1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2 == 0, s] // ToRadicals;N[sol]
```

> `{{s -> -1.49022}, {s -> -0.524889}, {s -> 1.00755 - 0.513116 I}, {s -> 1.00755 + 0.513116 I}}`

At least one of the results `a` and `b` is not true. I cannot numerically verify these because

```
NIntegrate[Exp[I*s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2) - Exp[I*s], {s, -Infinity,sol[[1, 1, 2]],
sol[[2, 1, 2]], Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4]
```

produces `-3.62952953475895858897998849318828745270 +  30.33384783506923620920956921799728322119 I` and a warning "NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in s near {s} = {-1.49021612009995364811638684235445262003720224040232564447871916489713786748684335358978576}.
NIntegrate obtained -3.62952953475895858897998849318828745269524061503385359582374023475829095533142179709562225+<<94>> I
and 3.12595523476650955449659895306705352885919834467455046353979227028938660290821997839067389`90. for the integral and error estimates."

In a simpler case, both

```
Integrate[Exp[I*x]/(1 - x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

and

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[2*Pi]*FourierTransform[1/(1 - x^2), x, s] /. s -> 1]
```

result in `\[Pi] Sin[1]`.

So the question arises: is `a` or `b` correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2 == 0, s] //ToRadicals; 
(Pi*I*Residue[Exp[I*s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2) - Exp[I*s], {s,sol[[1, 1, 2]]}] + 
Pi*I*Residue[Exp[I*s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2) - Exp[I*s], {s, sol[[2, 1, 2]]}] + 
2*Pi*I*Residue[Exp[I*s]/(1 + s/(s^2 - 1)^2) - Exp[I*s], {s, sol[[4, 1, 2]]}])//N
```

> `-0.998307 - 0.313707 I`

confirms `b`.